# Consolidate data and provide average of the consolidated data

Tags: vba, excel, consolidation

I am writing a macro, which will be used to consolidate data from a range of cells. I have the table with the data that I want to consolidate in sheets("1") in Range D2:J6 and the destination location is again in sheets("1") in M2:R2 (the colums M to R but they contain headers) . I have already written a part of the code below, which applies and runs for them. However, even though it doesnt say it has an error, it just wont run correctly.. I am prividing the screenshot from my excel after the macro runs ..

as you can see from the image, I want to consolidate the duplicate values in row D and print the average of the values located in columns E,F,G, H, I ,J on the same row as the consolidated values in column D. For example for the value "Gebze 6832" in column D, I want to remove it as a duplicate, make it one cell in the destination and print the average of the columns E,F,G, H, I ,J from the two rows that were consolidated next to it in the destination columns.

My code is below (UPDATE)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dataRng As Range
Dim dic As Variant, arr As Variant
Dim cnt As Long
Set ws = Sheets("1")
With ws
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column D
Set dataRng = .Range("D2:D" & lastrow)              'range for Column D
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = dataRng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
Next
.Range("M2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.keys)   'uniques data from Column D
.Range("Q2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.items)
cnt = dic.Count
For i = 2 To cnt + 1
.Range("N" & i & ":P" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",$M" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastrow & ")/" & dic(.Range("M" & i).Value)
.Range("R" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastrow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",0))=0,N" & i & ","""")"
.Range("S" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastrow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",0))=0,Q" & i & ","""")"
.Range("T" & i).Formula = "=IF($S" & i & ">0,SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$" & lastrow & "=$M" & i & ")*(($J$2:$J$" & lastrow & "-$E$2:$E$" & lastrow & ")>3%)),"""")"
Next i
.Range("M" & i).Value = "Grand Total"
.Range("N" & i & ":P" & i).Formula = "=AVERAGE(N2:N" & cnt + 1 & ")"
.Range("Q" & i).Formula = "=SUM(Q2:Q" & cnt + 1 & ")"
.Range("R" & i).Formula = "=AVERAGE(R2:R" & cnt + 1 & ")"
.Range("S" & i & ":T" & i).Formula = "=SUM(S2:S" & cnt + 1 & ")"
.Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value
End With
```

Comment: Of course, I cannot copy your screenshot into a worksheet to test it, but I would think a Pivot Table would do exactly what you describe.

Comment: Well, I figured it out with excel vba... my mistake was that I did not have the LeftColumn:=True line... thank you by the way for you advise....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in range `Column D to Column J` starting from `Row 2` and output has to be displayed from `Column M to Column S` from `Row 2` following might be helpful.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim dic As Variant, arr As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")  'change Sheet4 to your data sheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column D
        Set dataRng = .Range("D2:D" & lastRow)              'range for Column D
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        arr = dataRng.Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
        Next
        .Range("M2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.keys)   'uniques data from Column D
        cnt = dic.Count
        For i = 2 To cnt + 1
            .Range("N" & i & ":S" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",$M" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastRow & ")/" & dic(.Range("M" & i).Value)
        Next i
        .Range("N2:S" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value = .Range("N2:S" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code will give following result.

[image]

Comment: wow, thats a fantastic answer!since you wrote so analytically, do you think its possible to implement three minor changes?? First one is to consolidate up to column G (so up to Palls), and so occupy only the cells M,N,O,P in the destination table... second is to count the rows that have been consolidated for each row and paste them to the column Q (so for example, for Gebze 6832 have the number 2, for Atena 8860 number 1 etc)

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - Yup, give me sometime.

Comment: and third which is the most difficult one, be able to, in a way I am not really sure if its possible, consolidate the results in column N of the destination table only for the rows of the source table that have 0 in column I...

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - I've answered your another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881377/count-how-many-rows-are-consolidated-in-vba/45881679#45881679). Can you show how the output will be for `source table that have 0 in column I` condition.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but there is minor issue .. In the output of the code it is supposed to leave the cells with no value empty (no 0) . Now that I run the code, the column T instead of leaving the cells empty, it puts a 0. all the other columns work great! I tried changing the code, and the only thing I managed is to just make column T have empty cells , but then column S would have 0 on the empty cells (supposed to be empty ) .. I think it must be a really small change..

Comment: even better it would be to have all empty cells contain - instead of 0 but it is easy to fix that.. I will handle this!

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - If you want `Column T` to be blank (not have `0`) then in at the end of `.Range("T" & i).Formula ` change `,0)"` to `,"""")"`.

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - If you want this for all `Column R & S` also then for `.Range("R" & i).Formula = "` and `.Range("S" & i).Formula = "` do the same.

Comment: I did this already and it didint work ! I am uploading my code as an update to see how I have it.. maybe there is something I am missing!

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - In `.Range("T" & i).Formula` change `IF($S" & i & ">0,` to `IF(ISNUMBER($S" & i & "),`.

Comment: I promise I am not going to annoy you again! Just one last small change. I need to perform the consolidation exactly as it is performed right now, but only for the cells that are not empty(if there is 0 then the cell is NOT considered empty). I added a screenshot of my excel to make it more clear. For example, for Sochaczew I want to consolidate the 5 rows, but for each column of the consolidation, I want the average to be calculated only based on cell NOT EMPTY. so, in this case for example  column E based only on the value of cell E2. Thank you AGAIN!!