# count how many rows are consolidated in vba

Tags: vba, excel, count

I have created a macro that consolidates rows that contain the same value in column D and provides the average of the rows consolidated. I am trying to write a line of code inside the code provided below, which will count the individual rows that have been consolidated and paste the result next to the consolidated row (column Q) as it can be sheen form the pictures. Picture 1 contains the initial table and picture 2 contains the consolidated table. 
any ideas? Much appreciated!

UPDATE!

These are the updated pictures 
[image]
[image]

The whole process is PERFECT until the row Q (it was the last column before the update). I added three more columns to the destination table and one more to the source table.. if it is possible, I want for the column R the macro to  consolidate the rows and print their averaged Gross WFR delivered to the column R ONLY if the column I of the row is 0. Also, I want the macro to count these rows (containing 0) that it consolidates (just like it does for column Q) and print the number in column S. Finally, IF it is possible to count the number of these rows (containing 0) that are out of TARGET and print the number in column K. what I mean by out of TARGET is that for these rows K(values)-E(values)>3%.

FINAL UPDATE OF THE CODE

Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim dic As Variant, arr As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long

```
Set ws = Sheets("1")

With ws
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column D
Set dataRng = .Range("D2:D" & lastrow)              'range for Column D
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = dataRng.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
Next
.Range("M2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.keys)   'uniques data from Column D
.Range("Q2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.items)
cnt = dic.Count
For i = 2 To cnt + 1
.Range("N" & i & ":P" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",$M" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastrow & ")/" & dic(.Range("M" & i).Value)
.Range("R" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastrow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",0))=0,N" & i & ",0)"
.Range("S" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastrow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",0))=0,Q" & i & ",0)"
.Range("T" & i).Formula = "=IF($S" & i & ">0,SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$" & lastrow & "=$M" & i & ")*(($J$2:$J$" & lastrow & "-$E$2:$E$" & lastrow & ")>3%)),0)"
Next i
.Range("N" & i & ":T" & i).Formula = "=SUM(N2:N" & cnt + 1 & ")"
.Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim dic As Variant, arr As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")  'change Sheet4 to your data sheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column D
        Set dataRng = .Range("D2:D" & lastRow)              'range for Column D
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        arr = dataRng.Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
        Next
        .Range("M2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.keys)   'uniques data from Column D
        .Range("Q2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.items)  'count of shipment
        cnt = dic.Count
        For i = 2 To cnt + 1
            .Range("N" & i & ":P" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",$M" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastRow & ")/" & dic(.Range("M" & i).Value)
        Next i
        .Range("N2:P" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value = .Range("N2:S" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Assumption: Your data is in range `Column D:ColumnG` and want output in `Column M:ColumnQ`.

**EDIT :**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim dic As Variant, arr As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")  'change Sheet4 to your data sheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column D
        Set dataRng = .Range("D2:D" & lastRow)              'range for Column D
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        arr = dataRng.Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
        Next
        .Range("M2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.keys)   'uniques data from Column D
        .Range("Q2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.items)
        cnt = dic.Count
        For i = 2 To cnt + 1
            .Range("N" & i & ":P" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",$M" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastRow & ")/" & dic(.Range("M" & i).Value)
            .Range("R" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastRow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",0))=0,N" & i & ","""")"
            .Range("S" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastRow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",0))=0,Q" & i & ","""")"
            .Range("T" & i).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER($S" & i & "),SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & "=$M" & i & ")*(($K$2:$K$" & lastRow & "-$E$2:$E$" & lastRow & ")>3%)),"""")"
        Next i
        .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value = .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

***EDIT 2 :***

Instead of

```
.Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value = .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

write

```
.Range("N" & i & ":T" & i).Formula = "=SUM(N2:N" & cnt + 1 & ")"
.Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value
```

***EDIT 3 :***

```
Sub Demo_SO()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim dic As Variant, arr As Variant
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")  'change Sheet4 to your data sheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column D
        Set dataRng = .Range("D2:D" & lastRow)              'range for Column D
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        arr = dataRng.Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) + 1
        Next
        .Range("M2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.keys)   'uniques data from Column D
        .Range("Q2").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.items)
        cnt = dic.Count
        For i = 2 To cnt + 1
            .Range("N" & i & ":P" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",$M" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastRow & ")/" & dic(.Range("M" & i).Value)
            .Range("R" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastRow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",0))=0,N" & i & ",0)"
            .Range("S" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastRow & ",MATCH($M" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",0))=0,Q" & i & ",0)"
            .Range("T" & i).Formula = "=IF($S" & i & ">0,SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & "=$M" & i & ")*(($K$2:$K$" & lastRow & "-$E$2:$E$" & lastRow & ")>3%)),0)"
        Next i
        .Range("N" & i & ":T" & i).Formula = "=SUM(N2:N" & cnt + 1 & ")"
        .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("N2:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is the third change possible too? or is it something out of reach? thank you so much for this update... it works beautifully!!!

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - Can you show the output sample for third change.

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - What you have added is screen shot of your data. Could you add output result.

Comment: yes yes sorry.. I am just typing the question now... Actually, I am going to change my initial question.. give me a moment!

Comment: sorry for taking so long... I just wanted to make it really clear... Thank you for helping me !

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - give me sometime.

Comment: dont even mention it ! Thank you again! is it clear or do you want me to clarify it further?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - See edit in answer. But I don't see need of adding `Column K` as it is same as `Column J` so instead of `K-E` you can use `J-E` if I am not missing something.

Comment: man that is just great! And if I am not mistaken .. you have formatted the code in a way, that does not work only for a specific range, but up to the last row. And since the source table in my case is constantly going to change, then I can use the macro without changed it right ?? (the columns are going to be the same for the source shit, but the the rows may be more or less).

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - Exactly, code will handle any number of rows but same columns.

Comment: That is fantastic..man I am so THANKFUL! and one final question .. is it possible in such a macro, since it reads the last row, to add below the last row, an extra row with the totals (sum) of the cells in each column ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152846/discussion-between-mrig-and-pericles-faliagas).